# Add opaque subview to UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitextfield, opacity

I have a subclass of `UITextField` and I'm trying ot add an opaque subview to it.  However, when I type in the `UITextField`, it appears transparent and I can see the text behind the view.  How can I make the view fully opaque?  Here is the code that inits the subclass and adds the view.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
       _dropdownIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ab- dropdown-on"]];     
        dropdownIcon.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       _dropdownIcon.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-DROPDOWN_ICON_SIZE,0,DROPDOWN_ICON_SIZE,DROPDOWN_ICON_SIZE);
       [self addSubview:_dropdownIcon];
   }
    return self;
}
```

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: When you start typing I believe a text editor field is placed overtop  - I would instead layer the view over in the superview - or make a class MyTextfield with a UITextField subview and opaque view .

Comment: Didn't try, but what about `setBackgroundColor` or `setBackground` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subclass needs to override the `-textRectForBounds:` method to return the actual area you want text to draw in, e.g.

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect textRect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds];
    textRect.size.width -= 30; // or however wide your control is—play with this value
    return textRect;
}
```

What you’re seeing is not the icon being non-opaque—the text is just being drawn over it, because the text field doesn’t “know” the icon is there.

You might also look into the [rightView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/rightView) property and the related [-rightViewRectForBounds:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/rightViewRectForBounds%3a) method, though those are mostly useful if you want the text field to automatically show and hide your accessory view.